# Select Option value inserting None in Database - codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have populated the select options by using jquery ajax in codeigniter view. When I select `Village` from `Category` Type, `District` Select option is populated, selecting `District` gives me `Tehsils` and `tehsils` gives me `Union Councils`. The problem is with `union council` select option, it inserts `None` in database except of inserting its real value. Like 
`INSERT INTO 'hazara_tbl' ('HName', 'HDescription', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'CatagoryType', 'ParentID') VALUES ('ABC', 'blalbala', '123', '345', 'Village', 'None')`.
 Below is my code and images. Please help me. Thanks.

Controller

```
public function create_main()
{
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_data_model');
        $query = $this->insert_data_model->add();
        $data = $this->db->last_query();
        print_r($data);
        exit();
        redirect('insert_data/index/');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_data_model');
        $data['getDistt'] = $this->insert_data_model->getDisttforTehsil();
        $this->load->view('insertManual/main_insert', $data);
    }
public function getTehsilsForDistt($id="")
{
    $new =  $_POST['id'];
    $id = $this->input->post('HID');
    $data['query'] = $this->db->query("SELECT `HID`, `HName` FROM hazara_tbl WHERE `ParentID` = '".$new."' AND `CatagoryType` = 'Tehsil' ")->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
public function getUCForTehsils($idV="")
{
    $newV =  $_POST['idV'];
    $idV = $this->input->post('HID'); //receiving the ajax post from view
    $data['Vquery'] = $this->db->query("SELECT `HID`, `HName` FROM hazara_tbl WHERE `ParentID` = '".$newV."' AND `CatagoryType` = 'Union Council' ")->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

Model

```
public function add()
{
    $data['HName'] = $this->input->post('HName');
    $data['HDescription'] = $this->input->post('HDescription');
    $data['Latitude'] = $this->input->post('Latitude');
    $data['Longitude'] = $this->input->post('Longitude');
    $data['CatagoryType'] = $this->input->post('CatagoryType');
    $data['ParentID'] = $this->input->post('ParentID');
    return $this->db->insert('hazara_tbl', $data);
}

public function getDisttforTehsil()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT `HID`, `HName` FROM hazara_tbl WHERE `CatagoryType` = "District" ');
    return $query->result();
}
```

View

```
    <div class="form-group">
  <label id="lblCatType">Catagory Type</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="CatagoryType" id="CatType">
      <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Catagory Type</option>
      <option value="District">District</option>
      <option value="Tehsil">Tehsil</option>
      <option value="Union Council">Union Council</option>
      <option value="Village">Village</option>
      <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
      <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
      <option value="Medical Store">Medical Store</option>
      <option value="Gov Dev Project">Gov Dev Project</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  { 
    $("#lblDisttHotel, #disttHotel, #lblTehHotel, #tehHotel, #lblucHotel, #ucHotel, #lblVillageHotel, #villageHotel, #lblDisttNewUC, #disttNewUC, #tehNewUC, #lblTehNewUC, #lblDisttNew, #disttNew, #lblDistt, #distt, #lblTeh, #teh, #lblUC, #uc, #lblVillage, #village").hide();
    $('#CatType').change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == 'Tehsil')    // Tehsil selected
        { 
            $("#lblDisttNew, #disttNew").show(); 
            $("#lblDisttHotel, #disttHotel, #lblTehHotel, #tehHotel, #lblucHotel, #ucHotel, #lblVillageHotel, #villageHotel, #lblDisttNewUC, #disttNewUC, #tehNewUC, #lblTehNewUC, #lblDistt, #distt, #lblTeh, #teh, #lblUC, #uc, #lblVillage, #village").hide();
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Village')    // Village selected
        {
          $("#lblDistt, #distt").show();
          $("#lblDisttHotel, #disttHotel, #lblTehHotel, #tehHotel, #lblucHotel, #ucHotel, #lblVillageHotel, #villageHotel, #lblDisttNewUC, #disttNewUC, #tehNewUC, #lblTehNewUC, #lblDisttNew, #disttNew, #lblTeh, #teh, #lblUC, #uc, #lblVillage, #village").hide();
        }
    });
    $('#distt').change(function()
    { 
      var myHID = $('#distt').val();
      $.ajax(
      {
          url: 'http://localhost:83/ehazaratest/index.php/insert_data/getTehsilsForDistt',
          data: {id: myHID},  
          type: "post", 
          success: function( msg ) 
          {
            var aa = JSON.parse(msg);   
            $("#teh, #lblTeh").show(); 
            $('#teh').empty();
            $.each(aa.query, function (key, value) {    
                $("#teh").append($('<option></option>').val(value.HID).html(value.HName));
            })
          }
      })
    });   // end of function
    $('#teh').change(function()  
    { 
      var myVHID = $('#teh').val();   
      $.ajax(
      {
          url: 'http://localhost:83/ehazaratest/index.php/insert_data/getUCForTehsils',
          data: {idV: myVHID},
          type: "post",
          success: function( msg ) 
          {
            var getData = JSON.parse(msg);
            $("#uc, #lblUC").show();
            $('#uc').empty();
            $.each(getData.Vquery, function (key, value) { 
                $("#uc").append($('<option></option>').val(value.HID).html(value.HName));
            })
          }
      })
    });   // end of function
  }); 
</script>

<!-- Select District for Village -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="lblDistt">Select District for Village</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="distt" name="" > 
    <?php  foreach ($getDistt as $d )  {    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $d->HID; ?>"> <?php echo $d->HName;?> </option> 
    <?php  }   ?>
  </select> 
</div>

<!-- Select Tehsil for Village-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="lblTeh">Select Tehsil for Village</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="teh" name="">
      <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Tehsil</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- Select Union Council for Village -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="lblUC">Select Union Council for Village</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="ParentID" id="uc">
      <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Union Council</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[image: View]

[image: Output]

Comment: Why calling MySQL queries  from your Controller ? Wrong practice.

Comment: I am on testing phase right now, that's why using controller @AkshayP

Comment: DId you get the idea what my problem is ? @AkshayP

Comment: Are you sure you had data in `ParentID`?

Comment: Yes, i am sure, you can see here @Poonam
https://snag.gy/A2vN1M.jpg

Comment: Had you tried to print `$data` before inserting it in table?

Comment: No, i just print the last query executed and it insert None in ParentID

Comment: @Hamza Javed have your problem is solved or not?